# laravel how to create notification tables?

Tags: php, laravel, notifications

I am creating a social network with laravel and I would like to know if it is a good practice to create different notification tables, that is, a table to store friendship requests and another for the activities of the users within the page, my question is Can it be done this way ?, or should I use custom channels

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to know if it is a good practice to create different notification tables

I  would say no, a friend ship request is not a notification because the user can accept it or not.

When user A ask for friend user B you will have two objects :

1. a friend request which can be accepted or declined
2. a notification (of type NewFriendRequest) for the user B which informs the user of the friend request

Answer (score 0):

Read [this article](https://www.codedodle.com/2014/12/social-network-friends-database.html) about friendships in Social Media, notifications are a separate matter, try you could create a one(user) to many(notifications) relationship.